# AngularJS ng-repeat without markup?

Tags: angularjs

Question:

How can I use ng-repeat without injecting markup?

The  trick doesn't seem to work (working example==correct answer). The -start, -end trick won't work.

I've found solutions that come close, but I'm using ul/li, not a table. So...

Obviously, I can't put a div between the ul and li.

A directive is the easy way out, but I was hoping to avoid that in this scenario.

Update:

I now realize that no one understood my question because my code didn't post. I'm a StackOverflow noob. The following is the code I was referring to, but didn't post correctly:

```
<ul>
[[REPEAT]]
<li ng-show="something"></li>
<li ng-show="otherthing"></li>
[[/REPEAT]]
</li>
```

Comment: You want to add an `ng-repeat` without touching the HTML? That's not possible. I suppose you could use regular javascript to add that as an attribute to an existing element... but that would still be modifying the HTML.

Comment: can you post some code scenario?

Comment: I would not recommend using Angular if you cannot insert any of the app logic into your markup.

Comment: Oh, ha... no I didn't mean it as a universal restriction. Sorry. I just meant that I'm not allowed to put anything else in my ul/li. But let's face it: HTML doesn't even want you to put anything between them.

Comment: I've updated the question to be more clear. The way I worded it was insane. you'd think <ng-repeat /> would work, though. Example == answer.

Comment: There's no start and end tag to the ng-repeat, you simply add it as a directive on the element you want to be repeated. In this case a `li` within the `ul`. @BillyMoon has the correct answer below

Comment: Go find the CSS guy who gave you that stupid rule and bitch-slap him. Then go use Angular the way it was meant to.

Comment: For the time being, I'm going down the directive route (a workaround). Though, <ng-repeat="a in b"></ng-repeat> comes close to working. Possible bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat-start="a in b"  ng-show="something"></li>
   <li ng-repeat-end             ng-show="otherthing"></li>
</li>
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Can you put the repeat directive on the li element, without creating another HTML element...?

```
<div ng-app>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in ['first','second','third']">{{item}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/billymoon/pen/JdkuB/

Comment: Quite sorry. I've correctly posted my code this time. Obviously, a simple in-element ng-repeat is just Angular 101.